Google's "browse by name" or `gfns` query parameter
For over 8 years I've been using gfns parameters (also known by "browse by name" by some plugins) as my default search engine in Chrome/Firefox/Safari. It enabled me to search for a string and if Google could associate it with a specific url with a high degree of confidence it would just send me straight to the link.
Over the last couple of years that search parameter has become more and more unreliable and over the last few months has stopped working entirely.
I'm curious if anyone knows:

why this happened
if this functionality is still accessible, if so, how
if it's not accessible, if there are any alternatives that operate the same way

For 3, I'd like to maintain the same behaviour as now, so:

Searches with high confidence url matches just get directed to (e.g. stackexchange superuser should just go to the website)
Any other search falls back to a Google search

Anyone have any insights/advice?

Welcome to Superuser. Question posts should have a single question, not the 3 questions yours has. Have you cleared cache, tried different browsers on different systems, etc? Edit your question to focus on a single question, and include details of what you have tried so far.
